# macro for deleting selected rows from org table

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have some `org` table with 5 columns and 100 rows.

I would like to delete all those rows with `field $3="away"`.

Below is the function that should do the following. Unfortunately I do not know how to convert `org` table that is created with (`org-table-to-lisp`), back to text table into my buffer.

```
(defun org-table-tests ()
  "acts on balance table itself"
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (unless (org-table-p)
      (error
       "You are not in an org-table."))
    (goto-char (org-table-begin))
    (let (out-tbl
          (tbl-list (org-table-to-lisp)))
      (while
          (let ((row-list (car tbl-list)))
            (cond ((and
                    (listp row-list)
                    ;; do not copy "away" (3rd column) lines containing folliwng:
                    (string-match "away" (nth 2 row-list)))
                   ;; just skip copying to new table
                   )
                  (t (setq out-tbl (cons row-list out-tbl))))
            (setq tbl-list (cdr tbl-list))))
      ;;(orgtbl-to-generic out-tbl)  <---------- QUESTION: which function to use to convert back to table in text format.
      )))
```

... or maybe there is a better way for doing such tasks with `orgtbl` mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your main question was answered, here's now a solution that doesn't rely on converting to lisp and back :

```
(defun org-table-tests ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (unless (org-table-p)
      (error "You are not in an org-table."))
    (goto-char (org-table-begin))
    (while (org-table-p)
      (if (string-match "away" (save-excursion (org-table-get-field 3)))
          (delete-region (point) (progn (forward-line) (point)))
        (forward-line)))))
```

Comment: much cleaner solution:)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `org-listtable-to-string`. It's the reverse of `org-table-to-lisp`.

Also have a look at [this screencast](https://vimeo.com/86894158) to see how
I've found the solution in under a minute (just grepped for "to table" in org's code base, basically).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove row where $3=="away", following commands are useful. But I don't know why it works.

`ESC M-<`

`M-x flush-lines`

`RET`

```
^[|][^|]*[|][^|
]*[|] away [|]
```

`RET`

Input:

```
|    1 |    2 |    3 |    4 |    5 |
|------+------+------+------+------|
| away |   12 |   13 |   14 | away |
|   21 |   22 | away |   24 |   25 |
|   31 | away |   33 | away |   35 |
```

Output:

```
|    1 |    2 |    3 |    4 |    5 |
|------+------+------+------+------|
| away |   12 |   13 |   14 | away |
|   31 | away |   33 | away |   35 |
```